# JSON response with various data types

Tags: json, extjs

I have a JSON response like this

```
"{"total":1,"userBeanId":300,"list":[{"errors":[],"success":true,"liferayUserId":31503,"companyId":null,"groupId":null,"locale":null,"status":null,"liferayUserGroupId":null,"idProvider":null,"idClient":null,"userType":4,"userId":200,"email":"xpto@gmail.com","telefone":"999999999","nome":"MYNAME","role":"MY_ROLE","perfil":"Administrator","lastName":null}],"success":true}"
```

and what I have is a store that reads the list content, like this

```
"Ext.define('

MYPROJECT.store.Profiles', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'MYPROJECT.model.Profile',
    autoLoad: true,
    pageSize: 10,
    remoteSort: true,
    remoteFilter: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            read: '/delegate/rlapi-common/profile/list'
        },
        enablePaging: true,
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'list',
            successProperty: 'success'
        }
    }
});"
```

and the store "reads" the list successfully. However, I'd like to be able to access the "userBeanId" field as well. Is there any way I can access it by this store (by changing the root to something on an upper-level)? It confuses me as the store "maps" to a model and the userBeanId doesn't fit in the model.

Model:

```
Ext.define('MYPROJECT.model.Profile', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
             'userId',
             'nome',
             'telefone',
             'email',
             'role',
             'perfil'
            ],
});
```

Comment: ", I'd like to be able to access the "userBeanId" field as well" from where ,plus can u show your model as well

Comment: Post updated with model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access `store.proxy.reader.rawData` to get the most recently loaded JSON. As you suggested, it doesn't make sense being part of the model, but you can read extra meta info via the reader.

Comment: Thank you. To the people who share the same doubts, for further details, please refer to http://all-docs.info/extjs4/docs/source/JsonReader.html.

Comment: In my case, var userBeanId = store.proxy.reader.rawData.userBeanId;